# Derivation of arithmetic variation of a portfolio over multiple periods

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, variance, expected-return, proof

I am very confused on how to derive the attached equation (15).

Would someone be kind enough to walk me through the proof?
[image]

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathbb{V}[r_{t,t+k}] = \mathbb{E}[r_{t,t+k}^2] - \mathbb{E}[r_{t,t+k}]^2$ and use equations (6), (12) and (13) to compute these expectations.

Comment: Hello, Thank you so much for your response @JejeBelfort!! If you expand the PI term from n=1 to k, and subtract 1. You are left with a long equation of r terms multiplied with each other which you then square. how do you simplify this proof and see the pattern? also where does the V(of R_t) come from in the answer? E(r^2)-E(r)^2 from the expansion I mentioned?

Comment: Since the $r_{t+n}$ are uncorrelated, you can write $\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{n=1}^k r_{t+n}\right] = \prod_{n=1}^k \mathbb{E}\left[ r_{t+n}\right]$

Comment: Why delete the attachment? The problem was: if the one day returns are iid $\mu,\sigma^2$, what is the variance of k-day returns? The original attachment is here https://imgur.com/a/t5OqN

Comment: @molly Don't vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$
$\newcommand{\V}{\mathbb{V}}$

First note that

\begin{eqnarray}
\E[(r_{t + n} + 1)^2] &=& \E[r_{t+n}^2 + 2r_{t + n} + 1] = \E[r_{t + n}^2] + 2\mu + 1  \\&=& (\V[r_{t+n}] + \E^2[r_{t+n}]) + 2 \mu + 1 \\ &=& \sigma^2 + (\mu^2 + 2\mu + 1) = \sigma^2 + (\mu + 1)^2 \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, since $r_{t+n}$ are *independent* random variables we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\V[r_{t,t+k}] &=& \V\left[\prod_{n=1}^k (r_{t+n} +1) - 1\right] = \V\left[\prod_{n=1}^k (r_{t+n} +1)\right]\\
&=& \E\left[\left(\prod_{n=1}^k (r_{t+n} +1)\right)^2\right] - \E^2\left[\prod_{n=1}^k (r_{t+n} +1)\right] \\
&=& \E\left[\prod_{n=1}^k (r_{t+n} +1)^2\right] - \left(\E\left[\prod_{n=1}^k (r_{t+n} +1)\right]\right)^2 \\
&=& \prod_{n=1}^k \E[(r_{t+n} +1)^2] - \left(\prod_{n=1}^k \E[r_{t+n} +1]\right)^2 \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& \prod_{n=1}^k [\sigma^2 + (\mu + 1)^2] - \prod_{n=1}^k(\mu + 1)^2 \\
&=&[\sigma^2 + (\mu + 1)^2]^k - (\mu + 1)^{2k}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you so much for working through that in such basic terms!! I really appreciate your time and help.